# How to convert a column of float numbers in brazilian currency in spark-sql/pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In spark-sql or pyspark I have to convert a float number in Brazilian currency.
I'm doing:

```
data=[('bruce','wayne','1950-01-01','Male',9876543.21)]

columns=["NAME","LASTNAME","DOB","SEX","GOLD"]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=columns)

df= df \
.withColumn("GOLD_STRING",spf.concat(spf.lit("R$ "),
                                    spf.when(spf.substring(df.GOLD.cast("string"),-21,3)!="",spf.concat(spf.substring(df.GOLD.cast("string"),-21,3),spf.lit('.'))).otherwise(""),
                                    spf.when(spf.substring(df.GOLD.cast("string"),-18,3)!="",spf.concat(spf.substring(df.GOLD.cast("string"),-18,3),spf.lit('.'))).otherwise(""),
                                    spf.when(spf.substring(df.GOLD.cast("string"),-15,3)!="",spf.concat(spf.substring(df.GOLD.cast("string"),-15,3),spf.lit('.'))).otherwise(""),
                                    spf.when(spf.substring(df.GOLD.cast("string"),-12,3)!="",spf.concat(spf.substring(df.GOLD.cast("string"),-12,3),spf.lit('.'))).otherwise(""),
                                    spf.when(spf.substring(df.GOLD.cast("string"),-9,3)!="",spf.concat(spf.substring(df.GOLD.cast("string"),-9,3),spf.lit('.'))).otherwise(""),
                                    spf.when(spf.substring(df.GOLD.cast("string"),-6,3)!="",spf.concat(spf.substring(df.GOLD.cast("string"),-6,3),spf.lit(','))).otherwise(""),
                                    spf.when(spf.substring(df.GOLD.cast("string"),-2,2)!="",spf.concat(spf.substring(df.GOLD.cast("string"),-2,3))).otherwise("00")))
df.show()
```

And as result I'm getting:

```
+-----+--------+----------+----+----------+---------------+
| NAME|LASTNAME|       DOB| SEX|      GOLD|    GOLD_STRING|
+-----+--------+----------+----+----------+---------------+
|bruce|   wayne|1950-01-01|Male|9876543.21|R$ 9.876.543,21|
+-----+--------+----------+----+----------+---------------+
```

Is exactly what I need, but is there a more simple/performatic way?
Thanks in advance!
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For number formatting, `format_number` function will print those number with `'#,###,###.##'` format. Though this still requires replacing the thousand and decimal separators using multiple `replace`s.

```
df = df.withColumn("GOLD_STRING", spf.expr("concat('R$ ', replace(replace(replace(format_number(GOLD, 2), '.', ';'), ',', '.'), ';', ','))"))
df.show()

+-----+--------+----------+----+----------+---------------+
| NAME|LASTNAME|       DOB| SEX|      GOLD|    GOLD_STRING|
+-----+--------+----------+----+----------+---------------+
|bruce|   wayne|1950-01-01|Male|9876543.21|R$ 9.876.543,21|
+-----+--------+----------+----+----------+---------------+
```